# Trying to query data from an enormous SQL Server table using EF 5

Tags: sql-server, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am working with a SQL Server table that contains 80 million (80,000,000) rows. Data space = 198,000 MB. Not surprisingly, queries against this table often churn or timeout. To add to the issues, the table rows get updated fairly frequently and new rows also get added on a regular basis. It thus continues to grow like a viral outbreak.

My issue is that I would like to write Entity Framework 5 LINQ to Entities queries to grab rows from this monster table. As I've tried, timeouts have become outright epidemic. A few more things: the table's primary key is indexed and it has non-clustered indexes on 4 of its 19 columns.

So far, I am writing simple LINQ queries that use Transaction Scope and Read Uncommitted Isolation Level. I have tried increasing both the command timeout and the connection timeout. I have written queries that return `FirstOrDefault()` or a collection, such as the following, which attempts to grab a single ID (an int) from seven days before the current date:

```
public int GetIDForSevenDaysAgo(DateTime sevenDaysAgo)
{
    using (var txn = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
    {                
        var GetId = from te in _repo.GetTEvents()
                    where te.cr_date > sevenDaysAgo
                    orderby te.cr_date
                    select te.id;

        return GetId.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

and

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetIDForSevenDaysAgo(DateTime sevenDaysAgo)
{
    using (var txn = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
    {                
        var GetId = from te in _repo.GetTEvents()
                    where te.cr_date > sevenDaysAgo
                    orderby te.cr_date
                    select te.id;

        return GetId.Take(1);
    }
}
```

Each query times out repeatedly regardless of the timeout settings. I'm using the repository pattern with Unity DI and fetching the table with `IQueryable<>` calls. I'm also limiting the repository call to eight days from the current date (hoping to only grab the needed subset of this mammoth table). I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with Update 5 targeting .NET v4.5 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I generated the SQL statement that EF generates and it didn't look incredibly more complicated than the LINQ statements above. And my brain hurts.

So, have I reached some sort of tolerance limit for EF? Is the table simply too big? Should I revert to Stored Procedures/domain methods when querying this table? Are there other options I should explore? There was some discussion around removing some of the table's rows, but that probably won't happen anytime soon. I did read a little about paging, but I'm not sure if that would help or not. Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the query that EF generated and the table structure, plus a query plan if you can.

Comment: First question: is there an **index** on your table that contains the `te.cr_date` column (either alone, or as the first column in the index)?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you only selecting data and don't change it. So why do you need to use `TransactionScope`? You need it only when you have 2 or more `SaveChanges()` in your code and you want them to be in one transaction. So get rid of it.

Another thing that i whould use in your case is disable change tracking and auto detection of changes on your context. But be carefull if you don't rectreade your context on each request. It can presist old data.

To do it you should write this lines near your context initialization:

```
context.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
```

The other thing that you should think about is pagenation and Cache. But as i can see in your example you trying to get only one row. So can't say anything particular.

I recommend you to read [this article](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2924201/microsoft-net/best-practices-to-improve-entity-framework-performance.html) to further optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to say if you have to go with stored procedures or EF since we speak for a monster. :-)

The first thing I would do is to run the query in SSMS displaying the Actual Execution Plan. Sometimes it provides information about indexes missing that might increase performance.

From you example, I 'm pretty sure you need an index on that date column.

In other words, -if you have access- be sure that table design is optimal for that amount of data.

My thought is that if a simple query hangs, what more EF can do?